# How to wait for a file to exist with php?

Tags: php, file, filesystems

I am using an asynchronous webservice which send me back a Job ID. The full response is then send by the webservice as an XML file (jobId.xml) to my server using a PUT request.

---

> After issuing the request to the webservice and getting the jobID, I
>   would like to know what would be the best (most efficient) way to wait
>   until the file is created into the PUT directory of my server?

---

I am thinking of a loop of file_exist() with a usleep() between each execution and with a timeout.

But I am sure that there is a better way.
Something like a listener...

The file can take less than a second to more than 1 minute to arrive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could use [`inotify`](http://docs.php.net/inotify) to watch for file creations in some directory.
2. Alternatively you could modify your PUT handler to notify your script. For example, you could create a named pipe, read from it (blocking), and modify your PUT handler to write on the pipe one it has written the file

Comment: Which one would be the most efficient? I will have to use it extensively.

Comment: I think both would be equally efficient; the script will wait, and will be awakened when a file is created

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand if you need the php process to remain active (not return and die) or not.

If not, consider using [incrontab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab).
It is like a cronjob but instead of running on preconfigured times, it is run according to file changes. You can configure it to listen to a directory, and when a file finished creating on the filesystem, the incronjob will fire your desired program.

This is a solution for a unix/linux OS. You did not mention your OS.

Comment: linux-only I guess, has it uses inotify

Comment: Yes I need the process to remain active in this case. But I didn't know incrontab and it could be useful for other application!